# Plesk cannot create subscription

Tags: apache, plesk, centos6, chown

I have a Centos Server and I had a demo site running on apache. 
I decided to install and use Nginx instead of Apache.
Everything went well until nginx user asked for my site folder permissions. 
So I did

```
chown -R nginx path/mysite_folder
```

then I wasn't able to login from FTP, Plesk also has a lot of errors.

I deleted my domain/subscription from within Plesk and then I tried to create a new one, but I couldn't, Plesk wasn't able to create a new domain/subscription and gave me this error:

***failed: Unable to create user protection directory:filemng: Error occurred during /bin/mkdir command***

Comment: plesk needs to be the owner of the files for it to create or modify

Comment: might be an idea to look at http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?259457-Will-Plesk-10-4-4-work-with-Nginx-instead-of-Apache

Comment: @LiamSorsby Thank you for your comment but this link can not help me solve my problem.

Comment: have you tried giving permission back to plesk?

Comment: @LiamSorsby Can you please help me how to give back to plesk permissions?

Comment: should be   sudo chown -R your_plesk_username:psacln path/your_folder

Comment: @LiamSorsby 1st question) Where can I find plesk username of group psacln? 2nd) When you say path/your_folder what do you mean? As I said there is no domain/subscription now. I can't even create a new one.

Comment: When you ssh into the folder this needs to be applied for instance onto your root web root folder for example if all your websites are on /var/www/vhosts/websites.... then apply it onto /var/www/vhosts/ so it applys throughout all of your websites. if you run cat /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f1 this will give you all the users on your system it might give you an idea

Comment: if you haven't changed the owner of all folders in the web folder then go to that folder and then run ls -la and it will give you the owner and the user of that folder

Comment: @LiamSorsby Unfortunately even this didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general ownerships and permissions can be restored.

For example if you modified only PP installation directory, you may run these commands in order to bring everything back to order:

*Permissions and ownerships **reset to their default settings:***

```
for p in $(rpm -qa | grep plesk); do rpm --setugids $p; done
for p in $(rpm -qa | grep psa); do rpm --setugids $p; done
for p in $(rpm -qa | grep plesk); do rpm --setperms $p; done
for p in $(rpm -qa | grep psa); do rpm --setperms $p; done
```

*The order in which you execute the commands is important.*

You can also verify the correctness of the ownerships you have reset by comparing them with those on a working server. If all those actions fail then you can always re-install or update Plesk to the [last version](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-whats-new/index.htm) (11.5: supports Nginx) the user rights will be updated.

When ready add your nginx user to the root group using `usermod` [command](http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-add-user-into-group-in-linux/).